# List of dates from historic dates from a reference date

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a list of weekday dates back from a reference date.  For example if my reference date was 2020-02-14 and I wanted a list of the last 10 weekdays I would like returned:

```
2020-02-14
2020-02-13
2020-02-12
2020-02-11
2020-02-10
2020-02-07
2020-02-06
2020-02-05
2020-02-04
2020-02-03
```

I have tried:

```
dateList = pd.bdate_range(end='2020-02-14',periods=10)
```

without success (I won't hard code in my actual code this is just for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `pd.bdate_range` with frequency `B` for business days and set the `end` argument the calculate backwards.

```
dates = pd.bdate_range(end='2020-02-14', periods=10, freq='B')
print(dates)

DatetimeIndex(['2020-02-03', '2020-02-04', '2020-02-05', '2020-02-06',
               '2020-02-07', '2020-02-10', '2020-02-11', '2020-02-12',
               '2020-02-13', '2020-02-14'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='B')
```

```
pd.Series(dates[::-1])

0   2020-02-14
1   2020-02-13
2   2020-02-12
3   2020-02-11
4   2020-02-10
5   2020-02-07
6   2020-02-06
7   2020-02-05
8   2020-02-04
9   2020-02-03
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```